# Gaussian basis function selection - Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gaussian

I'm looking to set up a linear regression using 2D Gaussian basis functions. My input training variables cover a two dimensional space. Before applying the machine learning (Bayesian linear regression), I need to select parameters for the Gaussians - mean and variance and also decide how many basis functions to use.

I am currently spacing the means (of a preallocated number of basis Gaussians) evenly over a grid, and just assuming constant variance. This is obviously not the best approach.
Any ideas on how to calculate these variables?

Comment: Not feeling competent enough to answer, but your issue is "model selection problem" - you may want to look it up. In general you shouldn't tune the parameters looking at the data - that spoils it, and inhibits generalization.

Comment: see Tom Minka's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824341/how-to-choose-gaussian-basis-functions-hyperparameters-for-linear-regression 
unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an established "best" way to do this